# How to poll a variable while executing a script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to continuously poll a boolean variable which i'm reading from a file while i'm executing a script.

The polling have to start if the script starts (that part is working). Only i want let it run untill the script is finished. Is it possible to do this?
Now i'm using below code. The problem is that every time i ask a question in the script, or a field must be filled in, the variable will be written there.

Can some one tell me how to handle this problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read var                 # read variable in specified file (0 or 1)       
do           
if  [ "$var" -eq "0" ] ; then  # if variable is 0 throw error message
    echo "error"
fi

# some code below
/
/
/
done </path_to_file/file        # specified path to file
exit                            # end of script, exit
```

Added entry with new code:

Placed #poll=... to keep the code better readable.

```
#!/bin/bash                              # start of program

while true 
do

#poll=`grep "1" /Path_To_File/File        # poll if variable = 1
if  [ -n "$poll" ] ; then varpoll=1 ; else varpoll=0 ; fi 

if  [ "$varpoll" -eq "0" ] ; then # if variable = 0 throw error message
echo "Warning"
fi

sleep 0.25    
done 
exit
```

Comment: What happens if the script is in the middle of doing something, and the file is changed to have 0?

Comment: As far as i see it, it would may be possible to detach polling into the subshell from the script, with while loop inside `(...)&` structure. Then script can go on and ask questions, write. But there's other Issue with while loop is that it may hoag cpu, unless you add a small delay, like `sleep 0.25`. Other thing is that your redirection will be a single shot. Maybe using tail is better, or read file inside infinite loop

Comment: @muru, the code is only working one time. Changes are not appearing immediately. To get a change visible i have to restart the script. At this time i'm experimenting to let the while loop run contentiously and output a change. Even if i do it with tail it's only working at the moment the script starts.

Comment: The loop structure is working quiet fine now. Instead of using read or tail i changed to grep. It's easier to store grep's output in a variable so far i found. There is only one problem left i was not able to solve: If i'm entering text in a text field, and in meanwhile the variable i'm monitoring has changed from 1 to 0 and back to 1. The 0 is not noticed. Is it possible to create a interrupt at any moment the variable is changing to 0? I added a new entry with the code i'm using now in the start post.

Comment: A solution i found is to let the endless while loop run in background in another terminal. I'ts not really a interrupt or great solution, but it's doing the task as i wanted. All thnx for the usefull input!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read var                 # read variable in specified file (0 or 1)       
do           
if  [ "$var" -eq "0" ] ; then  # if variable is 0 throw error message
    echo "error"
fi

echo "What is your name?";
read name </dev/tty;
echo "You entered: $name"; sleep 2;

done </path_to_file/file        # specified path to file
exit                            # end of script, exit
```